# Why does no Robinson Annulation occur after the Michael addition?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

> Under basic conditions a Michael addition reaction can be used to convert compound A into product C. Explain why no Robinson annulation cyclic product is observed?
>
> Compound A
>   [image: reactant A]
>
> Product C
>   [image]

I have worked out that the other compound involved in the Michael addition reaction would be compound B (below), but I don't know why no Robinson annulation reaction could occur after the Michael addition reaction?

Compound B 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

As illustrated in the following figure, **the Robinson annulation reaction involves two steps**.  The first step involves the **Michael addition** of a ketone enolate (the enolate derived from cyclohexanone in the example pictured below) to an $\alpha,\beta$-unsaturated ketone (methyl vinyl ketone below).  In a second step the methyl group adjacent to the carbonyl is deprotonated and undergoes an **intramolecular aldol condensation** to form the final product. This last step is very favorable since the reaction occurs intramolecularly and involves a favorable 6-membered transition state to form a stable 6-membered ring.

[image: Robinson annulation]

Often in Robinson annulations methyl vinyl ketone is used. **It is important that  the $\alpha,\beta$-unsaturated ketone have an alkyl group attached to the carbonyl** so that the enolate required in the second step can be formed.

> Explain why no Robinson annulation cyclic product is observed?

**In your example**, the phenyl vinyl ketone has no alkyl group attached to the carbonyl carbon - only a phenyl group. Hence, the enolizable hydrogens present in your **Product C** can only react with the other carbonyl through a highly-strained 4-membered transition state preventing any ring formation through an intramolecular aldol from taking place.

Comment: Either of the enolates at either acidic $\alpha$ position in C could form, but the intramolecular aldol would produce an unfavorable four-membered ring (angle strain).

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically it could. There is nothing stopping the Michael addition product from being enolised and when enolised there is little to stop the enolate attacking a different carbonyl.

When I say ‘little’, that was a little lie, though. The main inhibiting factor is the Baeyer strain on three- and four-membered rings. These rings are rather strained (try building them with a molecular model kit!) and thus do not form easily. Especially, a nucleophilic attack onto the carbonyl carbon would be very difficult if not impossible to perform if it generates a four-membered ring. You can also try that with a molecular model kit, and remember that the nucleophile has to attack the carbonyl group in the Bürgi-Dunitz angle of approximately $107^\circ$.

In a regular Robinson annulation, as Ron described, the Michael acceptor system can be enolised on the ‘far’ side of the ketone — the one where your molecule has a phenyl group. It is then this enolate that attacks the other carbonyl group to form a six-membered ring — one that does not have Baeyer strain and is generally the most thermodynamically stable ring system. Your system cannot do this as it is lacking α-hydrogens on the ‘far’ side of the Michael acceptor.